# How do I use the Law of Cosines to calculate an angle from three points?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, algorithms, coordinate-systems, angle

This is very simple to do in Geogebra, where I simply place the three points on the coordinate system, and use the "Angle" tool to click on the three of them, and immediately I receive an angle value on the 2nd point that I clicked of the three.

For example, using the Angle tool, when you click on (5,5) then (4,7) then (0,-1) you can see that the remaining value of (4,7) is 306.87 degrees, because 53.13 degrees have been eliminated by the region formed when I connected the three points. I hope I am being clear enough.

Now the issue is, I need to do this on paper, without Geogebra, and mathematics is not what I am good at. I've looked around, and people have said that the solution is to use the Law of Cosines and they mention *arccos.* I don't know how to apply this properly.

If someone could provide an example, it would help me a lot. For example, what if I wanted to do this with (7, 4) (5, 3) (0, -1)? Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Which point is the vertex?

Comment: Of (7,4) (5,3) (0,-1) the vertex is (5,3) - at least that is what I believe to be the case after a Google search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A=(7,4), B=(5,3),  C=(0,-1)$

\begin{align}
   a = BC = \sqrt{(5-0)^2+(3+1)^2} &= \sqrt{41} \\
   b = AC = \sqrt{(7-0)^2+(4+1)^2} &= \sqrt{74}\\
   c = AB = \sqrt{(7-5)^2+(4-3)^2} &= \sqrt{5}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
   \cos \angle B 
   &= \dfrac{a^2-b^2+c^2}{2ac} \\
   &= \dfrac{41-74+5}{2\sqrt{205}} \\
   &= -0.97780
\end{align}

$$\text{So} \quad m\angle B = 167.9^\circ$$

Comment: I have arrived at -0.9943 and that turns out to be nearest to 6.0 degrees according to the cos table. But when I check in Geogebra, it's 192.09 degrees. Do you know where I went wrong? Is the calculation itself incorrect, am I reading the table wrong, or am I misinterpreting Geogebra? Thank you a lot for the example, it makes this easier to understand.

Comment: I just ran GeoGebra and got $167.91^\circ$

Comment: You are correct, 360-192.09 turns out to be 167.91. I was viewing 192.09 as the final value, not the other end of it. I also didn't place square root at the division part, but wrote 2*41*5. Two errors at once, but now I understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the law of cosines, you start by using the distance formula $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$ to compute the length of each of the sides in the triangle formed by your three points.

Then you can use the law of cosines $$ c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - ab\cos C $$ to isolate $\cos C$. Once you know $\cos C$, take the inverse cosine function (arccos, often written $\cos^{-1}$ on calculators) of that to find the angle $C$.

Since in most of the terms here you only need the *square* of the side, there's no need to compute the square roots in the distance formula explicitly. You'll just need a single square root for $ab=\sqrt{a^2b^2}$.

---

However, if you start with coordinates, it may be easier to simply compute the angle between each of your lines and the $x$-axis by
$$ \tan v = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1} \qquad\text{so}\quad
v = \tan^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\Bigr) \;\;\bigl[\pm 180^\circ\text{ if }x_2<x_1\bigr] $$
and then subtract those angles.

Comment: What would y2, y1 or x1, x2 be, if we're dealing with (7,4) (5,3) (0,-1) where the vertex is (5,3)?

Comment: @ManWithAFlute: $(x_1,y_1)$ are the coordinates of one point; $(x_2,y_2)$ are the coordinates of another.

Comment: What about the third point? I apologize if this sounds really silly, but like I said, mathematics is not my focus at all. Thanks.

Comment: @ManWithAFlute: Each of the formulas I quote are about a line segment from one point to another. In the law-of-cosines solution you need to use it three times, once for each side of the triangle. In the tangent solution you use it twice, once for each line segment that involves your vertex.